# Get user role by ID WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I need to somehow check someone's role with only their id.
I have found the `current_user_can()` check. But this only works for people that are logged in. How would I check for this if that user isn't the current user? I am using a phone order system but that uses the admin/specific account to order for other people.

Comment: Like described, I use a special phone order system. Orders are sometimes placed for a specific user by (for example) admin. And when this happens I need to check the role of that original user

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To check if a user has a specific role, you have to get a list of their roles and see if the role is listed there.

**Example function:**

```
function user_has_role($user_id, $role_name)
{
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;
    return in_array($role_name, $user_roles);
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$user_is_subscriber = user_has_role(get_current_user_id(), 'subscriber');
```

Comment: `$user_meta=get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles=$user_meta->roles;
if (in_array("subscriber", $user_roles)){}` Results in a role check for subscriber.

Answer (score 29):

The info you need to know before you proceed:

- You can't get user role by ID directly.
- You *can* get all the roles a user is assigned to.

Let's get all the roles and check if the role you're interested in is there or now.

```
<?php

// Get the user object.
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );

// Get all the user roles as an array.
$user_roles = $user->roles;

// Check if the role you're interested in, is present in the array.
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles, true ) ) {
    // Do something.
    echo 'YES, User is a subscriber';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hello try this optimal code

```
if (get_userdata($post->post_author)->roles[0] == 'your_specified_role'){
   echo 'role exist';
}else{
   echo 'role does not exist';
}
```

Comment: A user can have multiple roles in WordPress, so the correct way to assert is `in_array`

Comment: @LucasBustamante - Do you mean that a user can have multiple capabilities but a single role e.g. Editor?

Answer (score -3):

```
$user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user_roles, true ) ) {
    //echo User is a administrator';
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks an awful lot like [Ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719421/479156) of 3 months ago. Does this add anything new?