# Hiding a specific menu for a specific user group

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu "Become VIP" on my top main menubar. I created a particular user role who will get VIP access. If someone adds this user group, I want the "Become VIP" menu to be disabled from the top main menubar. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You’re gonna want to add a conditional in your template. You can find the code snippet you need here: [Get user role by ID WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720949/get-user-role-by-id-wordpress)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).